# What are the requirements for a font (OTF or TTF) so it works well on Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, fonts, android-view, typography

I'm having have some issues with using a custom font ( Typeface ) in Android.

What happens is that when rendering text in a TextView, the last line is often partially cut off vertically (the lower parts of letters like g, j, y, etc missing) , even if there's PLENTY of space below the text. I assume this is because there's something wrong with the custom font file ( an OTF file) that I'm using. This does only happen when using this custom font. If I use Android standard fonts, not setting my custom typeface, everything works fine.

Question: What are the requirements for font files for Android, so that they work correctly. (Please don't post workarounds for the issue, I'm aware of those. )

Comment: Which font type are you trying ?

Comment: Using OTF files right now. (not sure if I understand your question)

Comment: ok, but which style of font ? i.e. Tahoma

Comment: That is not relevant for this question. It's a general question about any type of font.

Answer (score 0):

Both OTF & TTF fonts Will work fine in android,You have to take care of textsize and paddings arround it.